# Laravel 5: What is the safe way to use .env in root directory?

Tags: security, laravel-5.3

In .env file which is based in the root directory, is it safe to provide below information:

```
DB_DATABASE=homestead
DB_USERNAME=homestead
DB_PASSWORD=secret

MAIL_DRIVER=sendmail
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=someemails@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=somepassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
........
........
```

Please advise the most secure way.

Comment: it is safe as long as you don't expose it to public. only `public` directory that should be accessible to public.

Comment: I don't get what you mean by "expose it to public". Do you refer to folder permission? Could you explain please?

Comment: well, as you see in this [example of laravel setup in shared hosting](https://laravel.io/forum/03-06-2015-how-to-setup-laravel-5-in-shared-hosting).